# How do git credentials work when cloning a private repo?

Tags: git, macos, github

I have a private repo on Github, which I have access to through my personal account. I'm on my work laptop, so most of the work is done with my work credentials. I recently cloned the repository in question with HTTPS via cli, `git clone https://github.com/org-name/repo-name.git`, and it did so without prompting my personal credentials. I do want to note, though, that in the past, I've worked on some projects through my personal account, so I'm assuming this is why the repo was cloned immediately.

I wanted to see if this was the reason and if my credentials were saved, so I tried doing `git config --list` and expected both my work and personal credentials to show up, but only my work creds show:

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=myName
user.email=workEmail
```

I've also tried `git credential fill`, but it freezes in terminal.

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong with any of this (also if the commands I included are correct), or if there's another way that I'm completely missing. I don't have experience with multiple git accounts, so I just don't wanna screw anything up.

Answer (score 0):

`user.name` and `user.email` are only for attributing authorship on any commits you make. They have **precisely nothing whatsoever** to do with authentication to GitHub, GitLab, or any other Git host.

Check the Keychain on that system. Does it have your personal GitHub credentials, your work credentials, or both? (Also, for completeness' sake, are you certain that that repo is private?)

Comment: Yes, the repo is private under an organization. I checked any possible keychains in Keychain Access - there was only one with an account number that I couldn't verify. After deleting it, I tried cloning again, but it immediately cloned again without any login prompt (also, another keychain was generated, so I suppose it is my personal credentials in Keychain Access). Could there be something else cached that would allow this?